# i want to send an auto reply to a new chat with whom i havent had a conversation earlier on Telegram

Tags: python, telegram, telethon

I'm new to Python and Telethon.

I've gone through the documentation of Telethon module.
I would like to send auto reply to a new person if they send me a message on Telegram private message.

I've found one (in [this gist](https://gist.github.com/yi-jiayu/acc31fbad5a25f746430428ce4d62c28))
which sends an autoreply to every incoming private chat. but i want to send a reply to new people only.

please guide

i want to check if user is present in the df below and send a reply accordingly.

code to get list of dialog id's is as below:

```
import time
from telethon import TelegramClient
from telethon import events
import pandas as pd

api_id = 123456
api_hash = 'enterownapihash'

# fill in your own details here
phone = '+111111111'
session_file = 'username'  # use your username if unsure
password = 'passwords'  # if you have two-step verification enabled

client = TelegramClient(session_file, api_id, api_hash, sequential_updates=True)
xyz = pd.DataFrame()
z = pd.DataFrame()
client.connect()
client.start()

for dialog in client.iter_dialogs():
    x = dialog.id
    y = dialog.title
    #print('{:>14}: {}'.format(dialog.id, dialog.title))
    xyz['dialog id'] = [x]
    xyz['username'] = [y]
    z = pd.concat([z,xyz],ignore_index= True)
print(xyz)
print(z)
```

***EDIT:
below is the code i've tried which hasnt worked.***

```
import time
from telethon import TelegramClient
from telethon import events
import pandas as pd

api_id = 123456
api_hash = 'enterownapihash'

# fill in your own details here
phone = '+111111111'
session_file = 'username'  # use your username if unsure
password = 'passwords'  # if you have two-step verification enabled

# content of the automatic reply
message = "Hello!"

client = TelegramClient(session_file, api_id, api_hash, sequential_updates=True)
xyz = pd.DataFrame()
z = pd.DataFrame()
#client.connect()
#client.start()

for dialog in client.iter_dialogs():
    x = dialog.id
    y = dialog.title
    print('{:>14}: {}'.format(dialog.id, dialog.title))
    xyz['x'] = [x]
    xyz['y'] = [y]
    z = pd.concat([z,xyz],ignore_index= True)

if __name__ == '__main__':

    @client.on(events.NewMessage(incoming=True))
    async def handle_new_message(event):
        if event.is_private:  # only auto-reply to private chats
            from_ = await event.client.get_entity(event.from_id)  # this lookup will be cached by telethon
            if event.client.get_entity != z['x'].values:
                if not from_.bot:  # don't auto-reply to bots
                    print(time.asctime(), '-', event.message)  # optionally log time and message
                    time.sleep(1)  # pause for 1 second to rate-limit automatic replies
                    await event.respond(message)


    client.start(phone, password)
    client.run_until_disconnected()
```

Comment: Hi @stricker21, welcome to StackOverflow! Could you post what you've tried so far?

Comment: @MZ kindly check. i've edited and posted the code i've tried

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way to do this is to fetch all the IDs present in your dialogs on start up. When a new message arrives, if their ID is not there, you know it's a new person (the code assumes you run it inside an `async def`):

```py
async def setup():
    users = set()
    async for dialog in client.iter_dialogs():
        if dialog.is_user:
            users.add(dialog.id)

# later, on a handler

async def handler(event):
    if event.is_private and event.sender_id not in users:
        # new user
```

Another option is to use [`messages.GetPeerSettingsRequest`](https://tl.telethon.dev/methods/messages/get_peer_settings.html), which will have `result.report_spam` as `True` when it's a new chat. Ideally, you would also cache this:

```py
user_is_new = {}

async def handler(event):
    if event.is_private:
        if event.sender_id not in user_is_new:
            res = client(functions.messages.GetPeerSettingsRequest(event.sender_id))
            # if you can report them for spam it's a new user
            user_is_new[event.sender_id] = res.report_spam

        if user_is_new[event.sender_id]:
            # new user
```

Comment: thank you for the comments @lonami

i've found an issue now. 
if a new chat ( event.sender_id) sends me more than 1 messages.
since the userlist is updated at start and the sender_id isnt appended into the list of userid's. even 3/4th messages. they are also replied to by the code.

is there anyway we can append the sender id to the list of userid's we have fetched when the program started?

EDIT:

            users.add(event.sender_id)
did the trick. sorry for the trouble. 
and thanks a lot :)

Comment: Please accept the answer if it solves your question, then.